# How to configure a BIND server to catch all

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver

I have a lot of domains

```
abc.example
def.example
ghi.example
jkl.example
```

Each of them are pointed to nameservers on their own domain

```
abc.example -> ns1.abc.example
               ns2.abc.example

def.example -> ns1.def.example
               ns2.def.example

ghi.example -> ns1.ghi.example
               ns2.ghi.example

jkl.example -> ns1.jkl.example
               ns2.jkl.example
```

These nameservers all resolve to the same IP where I am running a BIND server. I want this BIND server to act as a catch-all and respond with an A record to the same IP.

```
*    A     192.0.2.4
```

What I don't understand how to setup are the `SOA` and `NS` records. What would the zone file look like in order to achieve this?

Comment: All A records in all zones will point to the BIND server ip address?

Comment: @ALex_hha Yep, exactly! Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a reference zone file which is shared by all zones. The content of that zone file uses `@` symbol so no real zones name are referenced. The only trick is to use short names for the records (not FQDN names with trailing dots).

Reference zone file example:

```
$TTL 38400
@      IN      SOA     ns1 hostmaster (
                       2013102301
                       10800
                       3600
                       604800
                       38400 )

       IN       NS     ns1
       IN       NS     ns2

ns1  IN       A      192.0.2.37
ns2  IN       A      192.0.2.59

*    IN       A      192.0.2.4
```

Then, configure zones to use this zone file:

```
zone "abc.example" {
    type master;
    file "reference-zone.db";
};

zone "def.example" {
   type master;
   file "reference-zone.db";
};
```

Finally, you can use the same procedure for reverse zones.

Comment: Is there any way to make that reference zone file applicable to any domain so that I don't have to configure each zone to use the zone file? In other words, how can I make that reference zone file apply to *any* domain? Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: IMO, this is not possible with BIND. But it's not so complicated to prepare a simple template system to generate them.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of any other software that can achieve this?

Comment: Solved this using TinyDNS